# Implementing TableView in ScrollView doesn't show the table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

haven't spent a day without a stuck. I was trying to implement ***TableView*** in a ***ScrollView***, but it never showed up.

The code is here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "logTableCell")
}



var logs: [String] = ["Data1", "Data12", "Data13", "Data14"]

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return logs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "logTableCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = logs[indexPath.row]
    print("I am at table place")
    return cell
}   

}
```

And also a screen of StoryBoard
[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fi9c.png)

I checked the id of cell, tried to connect a tableView again, read/watched instructions how to do that, but it seems I am still doing something wrong. 
P.S. nothing is being printed in console from print() statement

Comment: Have you added proper constraints on the tableView?

Comment: @sats proper is what? I have constrains 0 0 0 0 to all borders, that is it

Comment: @sats and I am more afraid of issue that there is no Call of tableView functions as there is no Output in console from print statement

Comment: If you are using prototype cells you must not register the cells.

Comment: @Golgi Since the tableView is already inside a stack view, try setting the height of the tableView - say to 200. Also, try adding a background to the tableView, so that you will know if the tableView is taking up the right amount of space. And about the delegate methods not being called, if the tableView itself is not on the screen there is no point in calling these methods. So I don't think it will be called.

Comment: @sats you were right about height, I set it and tableView finally appeared. Thanks a lot. I actually thought about that, but putting a height constraint always occurred a red icon in StoryBoard.

Comment: @vadian thanks, i deleted that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `tableView` is already inside a stack view, try setting the height of the `tableView` - say to 200. Also, try adding a background to the `tableView`, so that you will know if the `tableView` is taking up the right amount of space. And about the delegate methods not being called, if the `tableView` itself is not on the screen there is no point in calling these methods. So I don't think it will be called.